# How Container failure is handled for a YARN MapReduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

How are software/hardware failures handled in YARN? Specifically, what happens in case of container(s) failure/crash?

Comment: What do you mean by containers here

Comment: The containers which are created by ApplicationMaster and which run MR jobs

Answer (score 5):

- Container and task failures are handled by node-manager. When a container fails or dies, node-manager detects the failure event and launches a new container to replace the failing container and restart the task execution in the new container.
- In the event of application-master failure, the resource-manager detects the failure and start a new instance of the application-master with a new container.

Find the details [here](http://www.otnira.com/2013/01/19/ha-in-yarn-motivation-and-proposed-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

- App master will re-attempt task that complete with exception or stop responding ( 4 time by default )
  _ Job with two many failed task are considered as failed job.