# How does cp command work in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am reading "Hadoop: The Defnitive Guide" and to explain my question let me quote from the book

> distcp is implemented as a MapReduce job where the work of copying is done by the
>   maps that run in parallel across the cluster. There are no reducers. Each file is copied
>   by a single map, and distcp tries to give each map approximately the same amount of
>   data by bucketing files into roughly equal allocations. By default, up to 20 maps are used, but this can be changed by specifying the -m argument to distcp.

and in a footnote

> Even for a single file copy, the distcp variant is preferred for large files since hadoop fs -cp copies the file
>   via the client running the command.

I understand why distcp works better for collection of files as different mappers are performing parallelly each on a single file. But when only a single file is to be copied why distcp performs better when the file size is large (according to the footnote). I am only getting started so it would be helpful if how cp command in hadoop works is explained and what is meant by "hadoop fs -cp copies the file via the client running the command.". I understand the write process of Hadoop which is explained in the book where a pipeline of datanodes are formed and each datanode is responsible to write data to the following datanode in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file is copied "via the client", the byte content is streamed from HDFS, to the local node running the command, then uploaded back to the destination HDFS location. The file metadata is not simply copied over to a new spot between datanodes directly as you'd expect.

Compare that to distcp, which creates smaller, parallel `cp` commands spread out over multiple hosts

Comment: "parallel cp commands spread out over multiple hosts" why parallal cp commands gets executed while considering single large file (only one mapper is responsible for single file)

Comment: Can you also please answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694747/how-container-failure-is-handled-for-a-yarn-mapreduce-job) question which asks how container failure is handled in YARN, the only answer states that it is handled by node manager but in some other places I have seen that application master handles container failure. @cricket_007

Comment: HDFS doesn't have "single large files", only you see that or it's how it is represented in memory. HDFS blocks are at most 128MB by default... Either you can copy 1,000x 128MB blocks to your computer one by one, or you parallelize it like DistCP does. And NodeManager does the tasks it's responsible for **after** the AppMaster has assigned the containers to the NM. The AM will restart itself in case of failure, not the remote tasks.

Comment: So by saying "Each file is copied by a single map" author means each split(128 mb by default) is copied by a single map, am I right? Say there is single file of size 1024 mb so there will be 8(1024/128) splits in hdfs. If there are more than one mapper, can I expect that the distcp will distribute the task of copying the splits among them?

Comment: I think when it says "each file", that is a reference to the actual files on the datanode which represent the blocks, not the HDFS file. And yes, a 1 GB file should get around 8 mappers

Comment: "And NodeManager does the tasks it's responsible for after the AppMaster has assigned the containers to the NM." Does that mean node manager will relaunch a container in case it fails? Or does it simply informs the resource manager about the failure and resource manger takes further action?

Comment: I am honestly not that familiar with the underlyings of YARN, but I do know that tasks will be re-attempted from the NodeManger in the case of failure, not the AM